# Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s). Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I was trying to Backup and recovery through Oracle 12c and everytime I went to shutdown the database, the listener and tnsnames.ora files get reconfigured and I don't know why. Now, everytime that has happened, I had to go to our DBA and he fixed it. Today he was on leave, so I spent the entire day trying to configure these two files in notepad++. So far I am convinced that what I have written in the tnsnames.ora file is fine. But the issue is with the listener.ora file.

Here are the contents of both of those:

tnsnames.ora file:

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

MISL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = misl)
    )
  )

JAHIN =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = jahin)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora file:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Jahin\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-TG0P7GL)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Whenever I try to check the status of the listener through lsnrctl status command, (I stopped and started the process after every change) it gave me a message that it found the service, how many instances it has, but it's status always returned Unknown.

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 27-OCT-2022 16:37:31

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                27-OCT-2022 16:15:54
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 21 min. 38 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Jahin\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Jahin\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-TG0P7GL\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-TG0P7GL)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

One more thing: whenever I try to login to sqlplus , I get a message saying connected to idle instance. And then it won't let startup or even shutdown the database.

```
C:\Users\Jahin Catalan Mahbub>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Oct 27 15:59:52 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> show parameter
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> show parameter uniq
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

SQL> startup
ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_MISL'

SQL> exit
Disconnected
```

any idea where the issue might be? Is it even in any of these places??

Now, AFAIR, when my DBA did it and he confirmed that it was working, the lsnrctl status would return 3 services, each of them had one instance, and every instance status was ready. All commands worked fine. Sunshines and rainbows.

The problem was that I didn't keep a copy of this listener.ora file the very last time he edited it and fixed it. I couldn't get any work done because of this.

Comment: Are you sure the files are being modified on shutdown/startup; you aren't just seeing different results from `lsnrctl status` - specifically that services listed before shutdown don't appear after startup? I would *guess* that the database just can't register with the listener when it starts up, and that could be down to how `DESKTOP-TG0P7GL` (and maybe `localhost`) resolve, particularly if you're using DHCP. The DBA might just be changing LOCAL_LISTENER to your current IP, for instance. Though from the startup error it looks like you should have a `LISTENER_MISL` entry in `listener.ora`?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with my DBA today and we have found a solution to my problem. Turns out, the listener.ora was mostly fine. I just needed to add one line to my tnsnames.ora file.

'
LISTENER_MISL = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SID = CLRExtProc)
(PRESENTATION = RO)
)
)

MISL =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = misl)
)
)

JAHIN =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = jahin)
)
)
'

Here is the minor changes that had been made to the lister.ora file:

''

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
(SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
(ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Jahin\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
(PROGRAM = extproc)
(ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Jahin\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
)
)

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-TG0P7GL)(PORT = 1521))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
)

''

I am not getting any significant errors so far, my DB starts up and shuts down without much issue.